# adding map to maui project

Tags: c#, xaml, maps, maui

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0400  The type or namespace name 'Maui' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)   MauimapApp3 (net7.0-android)    C:\Users\Dad\source\repos\MauimapApp3\MauimapApp3\Microsoft.Maui.Controls.SourceGen\Microsoft.Maui.Controls.SourceGen.CodeBehindGenerator\MainPage.xaml.sg.cs   18  Active
Iam trying to add map to maui project and I always get the same error any suggetion

I tried to install mauimaps from nuget and maui google map and I didn't resolve it

Comment: You mean after you right-click the project and add `Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps` NuGet package, that error will occur?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to install mauimaps from nuget and maui google map and I didn't resolve it.

You can implement map in MAUI projects by following the steps in the official document: [Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map?view=net-maui-7.0). The doc is very detailed.

In addition, it also provide code sample to display a map: [maui-samples/.../map](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/7.0/UserInterface/Views/Map).